# Expected Value of Borel Measurable Function

Tags: probability, expected-value, borel-measures

Let $A\  \in \  B(R)$  and $h:\  R\  \rightarrow R$ be a Borel measurable function such that, for any $x\in A^{c}$ , $h(x)\leq 0$
$x\in A$ , $h(x)\leq 1$. Prove that,for any random variable $X$ if $E\left[ h(x)\right]$ exists then:
$$E\left[ h(x)\right]  \  \leq \  P\  (\  X\  \in \  A\  )\  $$

I know that if  $A\  \in \  B(R)$ then $A^{c}\  \in \  B(R)$ thus making $x\  \in \  B(R)$ . But I don't know how to go from there.

Can someone help?

Comment: $Eh(X)=Eh(X)I_{A} (X)+Eh(X)I_{A^{c}} (X)$.